# ADC interrupt is interfering with while(1) loop on STM32. How can I fix this?

Tags: c, while-loop, stm32, interrupt, adc

I'm working on an STM32F303 and coding with STM32CubeIDE. 
I am working with an IR sensor and learning to read ADC input. At first I did everything within the while loop with no timers and without DMA and everything worked perfectly.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
/* USER CODE END 2 */     
 while(1)
{
      HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000);
      adc=HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
      sprintf(data, "%hu\r\n", adc);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)data, strlen(data), 1000);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
}
```

I decided to try the same thing with an ADC timer. So I flagged the ADC global interrupt in CubeMX and changed the code to the following.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
uint32_t adc;
char data[20];

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    if(hadc->Instance == ADC1) 
    {
        adc = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
      //  sprintf(data, "%hu\r\n", adc);
      //  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)data, strlen(data), 1000);
    }
}

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */


  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, "h", 1, 1000);
       HAL_Delay(500);

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

The ADC part works fine when I watch the value of adc or when I transmit it to my com port. The problem is nothing gets executed in the while loop. To test this out I disabled the ADC output to the com port and instead added a UART transmit to just send the letter 'h' to my com port. Nothing happens. But as soon as I disable `HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);` it immediately starts to work. Why am I having a problem with executing the while loop and the interrupt at the same time??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The inline version does not collect ADC data more frequently than it can transmit. You should not be making calls like `sprintf(data, "%hu\r\n", adc);` in an interrupt routine. A slow function like that is likely to make the system interrupt-bound. An interrupt handler should do the least amount of work possible, and pass the result (via a buffer say) to the upper layer for further processing. If that cannot process the input being passed to it faster than it is arriving (buffer overflow), you either have to slow down the reading rate, or discard some of the information.

Comment: You can't really program interrupts without a debugger and a scope.

Comment: My speculation is you stuck somewhere in the ADC interrupt handler forever, but as Lundin sad we can't really know what is going on in your system without debugger and scope

Comment: show iinitalization code

Answer (score 0):

I believe your sampling rate is too fast, change your sampling rate to a higher value (181.5 cycles) , it should work.
If you are using STM32CubeMX, the setting is in the ADC1 > configuration > parameter settings > ADC_Regular_Conversion_Mode > Rank > Sampling Time.